# Display two buttons in a row with flexbox and control alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Supposedly I have buttons, I want to display these buttons by 2 in a row. I'm not sure how I can display the buttons with a specific width in 2 in a row and have the control to display them left, center, or right. Wanted outcome would be something like this:

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">1</button>
  <button class="button">2</button>
  <button class="button">3</button>
  <button class="button">4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: why not two container and each one with 2 buttons?

Comment: @TemaniAfif because the buttons could be 4 or 6 or 8 and has a couple of existing customisations like being displayed in reverse

Comment: so add this detail into your question because it's important. handling 4 buttons is easy but not if the number is dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you set the width of the container? Then set margin-left/margin-right to auto to align the buttons?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 380px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">1</button>
  <button class="button">2</button>
  <button class="button">3</button>
  <button class="button">4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `flex: 0 50%` to child elements. It's can force it to arrange 2 items per row.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 20rem;
  /* Aligning elements left, center and right in flexbox */
  /* float: left; */
  margin: auto;
  /* float: right; */
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container>button {
  flex: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button">Button 3</button>
  <button class="button">Button 4</button>
</div>
```